# Combinações possíveis de (A a Z) e de (0 a 9)

Tags: php

Boa tarde,
Quantas combinações consigo usando de (A a Z) e de (0 a 9), usando apenas 3 letras e 3 numeros, ficando dessa forma:

**AAA-000**

E qual a forma mais segura para gerar esses numero e letras?

Asim ta valendo?

```
$a = substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0 ,3);
$b = substr("0123456789", 0 ,3);

echo $a ."-". $b;
```

Obrigado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tinha uma resposta sua ou do Jefferson que falava sobre o uso da lib itertools do Python, esta ai um bom começo

Comment: Caro Tiago é javascript ou PHP? Porque as sugestões que tenho em mente são bem diferentes.

Comment: As letras serão sempre maiúsculas ou podem diferenciar entre maiúsculas e minúsculas?

Comment: 26^3 x 10^3 combinações possíveis, pelo simples fato das posições serem imutáveis. Qual o propósito de se calcular isso?

Answer (score 4):

Funciona aproximadamente como abaixo. Vou tentar explicar da maneira mais simples que conheço:

Total de letras: 26 (levando em consideração apenas as letras maiúsculas do alfabeto comum)

Total de números: 10 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

A conta é basicamente: `26 * 26 * 26 * 10 * 10 * 10` (AAA-000)

O resultado é:

```js
var totalLetras = 26;
var totalNumeros = 10;

// baseado na string 'AAA-000'
var totalCombinacoes = totalLetras * totalLetras * totalLetras * totalNumeros * totalNumeros * totalNumeros;

console.log(totalCombinacoes);
```

Uma fórmula possível seria:

```js
function gerarCombinacao() {
  
  var combinacao = retornarLetra().toString();
  combinacao = combinacao.concat(retornarLetra());
  combinacao = combinacao.concat(retornarLetra());
  combinacao = combinacao.concat("-");
  combinacao = combinacao.concat(retornarNumero());
  combinacao = combinacao.concat(retornarNumero());
  combinacao = combinacao.concat(retornarNumero());
  
  return combinacao;
  
}

console.log(gerarCombinacao());

//retorna as letras do alfabeto a partir do charCode: 65 até 90 (A-Z)
function retornarLetra() {
  return String.fromCharCode(64 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 26)).toString();
}

// retorna os números de 0 a 9
function retornarNumero() {
  return Math.round((Math.random() * 9)).toString();
}
```

Em php:

```
<?php

function gerarCombinacao() {

    // retorna as letras de A-Z
    $combinacao = chr(rand(65,90));
    $combinacao .= chr(rand(65,90));
    $combinacao .= chr(rand(65,90));

    // adiciona o "-"
    $combinacao .= "-";

    // retorna os números de 0 a 9;
    $combinacao .= rand(0,9);
    $combinacao .= rand(0,9);
    $combinacao .= rand(0,9);

    return $combinacao;

}

echo gerarCombinacao();
```

Você pode ver esse código [funcionando aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05d7aca3936b585262676208415f859512e03b1e).

Comment: Ao que negativou: talvez seja por causa que o código pedido é em php. Editei a pergunta e acrescentei o código no fim. Se for por outro motivo, por favor me avise!

Comment: Tá completo até que seja editada.